# Given code is not working for given problem

Tags: c++, error-handling

**I do not have the cases which the site is checking, it only provides a example given below.**

**Input**
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
The second line contains N space-separated integers a1,a2,…,aN.
The third line contains N space-separated integers d1,d2,…,dN.

**Output**
For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the best defense value of the shield the king gets, or −1 if Chef can be thrown in the snake pit.

**Constraints**
1≤T≤100
3≤N≤100
1≤ai,di≤104 for each valid i

**Example Input**

```
2
4
1 1 4 1
3 4 2 1
7
5 4 5 4 5 4 5
3 2 4 7 2 5 9
```

**Example Output**

```
3
-1
```

**Explanation**

**Example case 1:** Soldier 1 can be attacked by soldier 2 and/or soldier 4. If only soldier 2 attacks him, the power of the attack is 1. If only soldier 4 attacks him, the power of the attack is 1 again. If they attack together, the power of the attack is 2. In each of these cases, soldier 1 will live.

Soldier 2 can be attacked by soldier 3, with attack power 4. His shield has defense value 4, which is not enough, so in this case, soldier 2 would die. The best safe choice is soldier 1, with defense value 3.

**Example case 2:** No soldier is guaranteed to survive the battle, so the answer is −1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    if(T > 100 || T<1) return 0;

    do{
        vector<long int> ans;
        int N;
        cin>>N;
        if(N > 100 || N<3) return 0;
        vector<int> attackArray(N), defArray(N);

        for (int i =0; i<N; i++) {
            cin>>attackArray.at(i);
        }
        for (int i =0; i<N; i++) {
            cin>>defArray.at(i);
        }
        if (defArray.at(0) > attackArray.at(1) && 
    defArray.at(0) > attackArray.at(N-1) && 
    defArray.at(0)> attackArray.at(1) + attackArray.at(N-1)){

        ans.push_back(defArray.at(0));

    }
    if (defArray.at(N-1) > attackArray.at(0) && 
    defArray.at(N-1) > attackArray.at(N-2) && 
    defArray.at(N-1)> attackArray.at(0) + attackArray.at(N-2)){

        ans.push_back(defArray.at(N-1));

    }


        for (int i =1; i<N-1; i++) {
   int nexti, previ;

    nexti = i + 1;
    previ = i - 1;

if (defArray.at(i) > attackArray.at(nexti) && 
    defArray.at(i) > attackArray.at(previ) && 
    defArray.at(i)> attackArray.at(nexti) + attackArray.at(previ)){

        ans.push_back(defArray.at(i));

    }
else {ans.push_back(-1); break;}

}

        sort(ans.begin(), ans.end(), greater<int>());
        cout<<ans[0]<<endl;

        T--;
    }while (T !=0);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's a long description. You should summarize like _the program should do this but it is doing this_. Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Please dont just dump the assignment and your code. Instead try to explain what is the specific problem and what you tried to solve it, also it helps to include a question in the question ;)